# JavaFX: Bind ObservableList to which view?

Tags: java, javafx, binding

I've got an ObservableList which holds some Pojos (containing name and imageURL information).
The list is made visible in a Popup as seen as in the attached screen.

As the ObservableList can change (filtering etc.), I would like to update the shown information in the Popup as well. I know that I can bind an ObservableList to a TableView or ListView - but how could I maintain the same layout (Grid) as shown in the attached screen?

I am therefore asking for an advice on how to implement this - Any suggestions are appreciated.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think `ControlsFX` `GridView` may work here. https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/wiki/ControlsFX-Features#gridview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TableView` and `ListView` are not suited to that style of layout.  The simplest solution is to use a `ListChangeListener` and rebuild the popup contents when you are notified.  It looks like you have something similar to a FlowPane filled with simple Label nodes.  Maintaining the child Node list by tracking changes to your list of POJOs should be relatively straight-forward.  There's a good candidate for a reusable class similar to the cell factories used by the Table/List "View" classes to be made.

Edit: I came up with something like this.

```
package stackoverflow.answers.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class NodeFactory<T> {

    private ObservableList<Node> nodes;
    private ObservableList<T> modelData;

    /** Constructs a factory for the childNodes of a Parent. Tracks the data list
     * @param childNodes mutable child node list of a Parent
     * @param data the data model
     */
    public NodeFactory(ObservableList<Node> childNodes, ObservableList<T> data) {
        this.nodes = childNodes;
        modelData = data;
        data.addListener(this::listListener);
        rebuildAllNodes();
    }

    private List<Node> buildNodesFor(List<? extends T> data) {
        ArrayList<Node> newNodes = new ArrayList<>(data.size());
        for(T datum : data) {
            Node node = buildNodeFor(datum);
            newNodes.add(node);
        }
        return newNodes;
    }

    private void rebuildAllNodes() {
        List<Node> newNodes = buildNodesFor(modelData);
        nodes.setAll(newNodes);
    }

    /**
     * Implementations of NodeFactory should override this method to construct the appropriate node for the given model
     * data.  You need not call the base class implementation which simply constructs a Label based on the String
     * representation of the model data, or if the model data is a Node, a Label that wraps the model as its graphic.
     * @param model the data to generate a Node for
     * @return Node used to render the given model data
     */
    protected Node buildNodeFor(T model) {
        if (model instanceof Node) {
            return new Label(null, (Node) model);
        }
        return new Label(String.valueOf(model));
    }

    private void listListener(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends T> c) {
        // rebuildAllNodes(); // worst case - we can do better

        while (c.next()) {
            if (c.wasPermutated()) {
                // avoid potentially costly reconstruction of nodes
                int from = c.getFrom();
                int to = c.getTo();
                ArrayList<Node> permutedNodes = new ArrayList<>(to-from);
                for (int oldIndex = from; oldIndex < to; oldIndex++) {
                    int newIndex = c.getPermutation(oldIndex);
                    permutedNodes.add(newIndex-from, nodes.get(oldIndex));
                }
                nodes.remove(from, to);
                nodes.addAll(from, permutedNodes);
            } else if(c.wasUpdated()) {
                int to = c.getTo();
                for(int index = c.getFrom(); index < to; index++) {
                    T model = modelData.get(index);
                    Node node = buildNodeFor(model);
                    nodes.set(index, node);
                }
            } else {
                if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                    int index = c.getFrom();
                    nodes.remove(index, index+c.getRemovedSize());
                }
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    int from = c.getFrom();
                    List<Node> newNodes = buildNodesFor(c.getAddedSubList());
                    nodes.addAll(from, newNodes);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Simple test program for above:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FlowPane flow = new FlowPane(8,8);
        NodeFactory nf = new NodeFactory(flow.getChildren(), data);
        flow.setUserData(nf); // just to keep track of it somewhere
        Button addButton = new Button("Add Item");
        Button removeButton = new Button("Remove Item");
        addButton.setOnAction(ae -> data.add("Item "+(data.size()+1)));
        removeButton.setOnAction(ae -> data.remove(0));
        removeButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(flow.getChildren()));
        HBox buttons = new HBox(10, addButton, removeButton);
        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane(flow, buttons, null, null, null);
        Scene scene = new Scene(bp);
        stage.setHeight(200); 
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: many thanks for your contribution. It makes sense, I was hoping there would be something that FX offers out of the box. But you're right, it's kinda straight forward :)

Comment: @Remo I've added a simple factory implementation

Answer (score 2):

I am exactly preparing to say what @swpalmer has said :) and preparing the demo. As his answer has all the wordings.. please find the below quick demo of what it means. May not be an exact solution, but will give you a conceptual idea.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class DynamicContent_In_FlowPane_Demo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<String> srcList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        srcList.addAll("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6");

        Map<String, Node> nodeMap = new HashMap<>();
        srcList.forEach(item->{
            StackPane sp = new StackPane();
            sp.setPrefSize(50,50);
            sp.setMaxSize(50,50);
            sp.getChildren().add(new Label(item));
            sp.setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;-fx-border-width:1px;");
            nodeMap.put(item,sp);
        });

        FlowPane fp = new FlowPane();
        fp.setMaxSize(202, 252);
        fp.setMinSize(202, 252);
        fp.setStyle("-fx-border-color:red;-fx-border-width:1px;");

        ChoiceBox<String> type = new ChoiceBox<>();
        type.getItems().addAll("All", "A", "B", "C","1","2","3","4","5","6");
        type.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        type.valueProperty().addListener((obs,old,val)->{
            if(val.equals("All")){
                updateItems(fp,srcList,nodeMap);
            }else{
                updateItems(fp,srcList.stream().filter(i->i.contains(val)).collect(Collectors.toList()),nodeMap);
            }
        });

        updateItems(fp,srcList,nodeMap);
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(type, fp);
        root.setSpacing(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        Scene sc = new Scene(root, 300, 350);
        primaryStage.setScene(sc);
        primaryStage.setTitle("FlowPane");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void updateItems(FlowPane fp, List<String> list, Map<String, Node> nodeMap) {
        fp.getChildren().clear();
        list.forEach(item->fp.getChildren().add(nodeMap.get(item)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your much appreciated input - I will try it with this way :)